# Sql Server: Define which row to consider

Tags: sql-server

I need help solving a simple problem I believe, because I trully suck at SQL.
So, everything in my query is working fine, but I need to tweak it to automate one process. I've a product in different warehouses (**AA.Armazem**) and my objetive is to select the stock (**AA.StkActual**) of only one of those warehouses, depending on the StockValue of each one.
So, I always want to consider **AA.Armazem = 'A7' first**, **then 'A8**', **then 'A9'**. I will only **consider warehouse 'A8' if the warehouse 'A7' has stock = 0**, and therefore, **consider warehouse 'A9' only when 'A7' and 'A8' are outta stock (AA.StkActual = 0)**.

Right now my problem is, since I want the minimum StockValue, I'm getting the AA.StkActual of the AA.Armazem = 'A9' when I should be getting the AA.StkActual of the AA.Armazem = 'A7' since it still has units.
P.S. **The component in question is from AA.Familia = 98.** There's components from other families but like I said, they're all in the 'A7' warehouse.

Here's my query:

```
    select
    A1.Artigo as Artigo,
    A1.Descricao as Descricao, (coalesce(MIN(
        case
            when AA.Armazem = 'A7' then 
                CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 39 THEN AA.StkActual / CA.Quantidade ELSE AA.StkActual END
            else
                null
        end
    ), MIN(
        case
            when AA.Armazem = 'A8' then 
                CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 39 THEN AA.StkActual / CA.Quantidade ELSE AA.StkActual END
            else
                null
        end
    ), MIN(
        case
            when AA.Armazem = 'A9' then 
                CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 39 THEN AA.StkActual / CA.Quantidade ELSE AA.StkActual END
            else
                null
        end
    ))) as Stock,
    0 as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes,
    'Componente Stock' As Id
from
    Artigo A1
    join ComponentesArtigos CA On CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
    join Artigo A2 On A2.Artigo = CA.Componente And (A2.Familia IN (37,38,39,45,98))
    join ArtigoArmazem AA ON AA.Artigo = A2.Artigo And (AA.Armazem IN ('A7','A8', 'A9'))
group by
    A1.Artigo,
    A1.Descricao
```

The query i've presented gives me the minimum stock as result, however, If I simply get all the components, I get this result:

[query with all components and without MIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFCiV.png)
As you can see on the image, the 'SBC' component is the one from AA.Familia = 98; I need the query to consider first the **AA.StkActual from AA.Armazem = 'A7', then 'A8', then 'A9' as I've explained, but only for component which AA.Familia = 98. It only considers the other Warehouse if the previous one has Stock = 0.**

If I run the query with the MIN conditional, I'll get the StkValue of 8 which isn't wrong, the thing is, **I need to consider the StkValue of 154 since It is on the 'A7' Warehouse**. So if you look at the query I've provived, I want to get the following result: [Query retriving the min StkValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqM2Q.png) -> The value 25 (50/2) comes from the component (DIMM DDR3) with the least stock (that's the info I need to know how many products I can build maximum), instead of getting that Stock = 8 since in this case I really need to consider the Stock from Warehouse 'A7' for component with AA.Familia = 98

I hope you've understand me, I did my best to show you the problem and what I want/need to do.

1st edit: **This is a subquery!**

2nd edit: **I've changed the query to the one I'm using instead of showing you the query destined for products of AA.Familia = 98.**

3rd edit: Better explained problem

4th edit: image below and updated the above query to the one I'm using/trying to work around with to get the solution.

[image: StockValue I need to get]
As you can see, I've circled the StockValues I need to get for 3 different products (25 ; 6 ; 12). However, the values I'm getting with Jeremy's answer are 25; 6; 15.

Each component (SBC,CPU,RAM,HDD,DVDRW) has its own stock. The stock = 6 for second product is because we've already 2 of those computers built, so with the query we're trying to get, the Stock = 4 basically.

How can I do that?

Best Regards

Comment: Order by Armazem "A7, A8, A9" and filter StakActual>0 then Take TOP 1 !

Comment: @NirmalSubedi I can't use order since this is a subquery :/

Comment: @TiagoCosta yes you can, if it has a `TOP` . `SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 Col FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3))V(Col) ORDER BY Col DESC) AS Col;` works fine.

Comment: @Larnu how and where should I define TOP? in this subquery or major query? This is the query I use to get the components of a product, however, there's only one product that can be in those 3 warehouses, all of the others are always in the 'A7' warehouse

Comment: In the sub query; like I show in the comment.

Comment: @Larnu that way I believe I can't get the MIN from the other products that aren't from this family (98)
I think I cannot add more columns aswell.. I'm a sql noob

Comment: A subquery in the **`SELECT`** can only return a scalar value, @TiagoCosta . If you need to return multiple rows/columns you need to move it to the `FROM`.

Comment: @TiagoCosta, I think you're going to need to make the issue replicable for us, and to eliminate the clutter.  Make create-table statements for relevant temp tables, provide insert statements for a few rows in each table, and point your query to those temp tables.  Then give a table of your expected results (this one doesn't have to be in SQL format).

Comment: @pwilcox I think you're probably right, that's why I've updated the question with more information. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to note that you really should change your aliases here for `Artigo`--having this named `A1` and `A2` when you also have data values in `AA.Armazem` named A7, A8, and A9 makes thinking through this quite confusing.

With that out of the way, you very likely want to pivot out your A7, A8, and A9 values before you start comparing them. You can use the [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) syntax if you want, but I don't think it's really warranted here. Instead,

```
    select
        A1.Artigo as Artigo,
        A1.Descricao as Descricao,
        MIN(
            case
                when AA.Armazem = 'A7' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 39 THEN AA.StkActual / CA.Quantidade ELSE AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ) AS StockA7,
        MIN(
            case
                when AA.Armazem = 'A8' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 39 THEN AA.StkActual / CA.Quantidade ELSE AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ) AS StockA8,
        MIN(
            case
                when AA.Armazem = 'A9' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 39 THEN AA.StkActual / CA.Quantidade ELSE AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ) AS StockA9,
        0 as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes,
        'Componente Stock' As Id
    from
        Artigo A1
        join ComponentesArtigos CA On CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
        join Artigo A2 On A2.Artigo = CA.Componente And (A2.Familia IN (37,38,39,45,98))
        join ArtigoArmazem AA ON AA.Artigo = A2.Artigo And (AA.Armazem IN ('A7', 'A8', 'A9'))
    group by
        A1.Artigo,
        A1.Descricao
```

You can then use the result of this query to prefer the A7 and A8 values.

```
    select
        Artigo,
        Descricao,
        coalesce(
            nullif(StockA7, 0),
            nullif(StockA8, 0),
            nullif(StockA9, 0)
        ) Stock
```

Comment: I believe you almost solved my issue, but If the component from AA.Familia = 98 is in the warehouse 'A8' and since all the other components are always in the warehouse 'A7', It will always prevail the 'A7' warehouse because It has other components with units

Comment: I need the 'A8' warehouse to prevail if the component which AA.Familia = 98 is the one with less units (comparing with all the other components from the other warehouse 'A7')

If an example helps:
SBC - Warehouse A8 - 12 units
CPU - Warehouse A7 - 30 units
RAM - Warehouse A7 - 20 units
HDD - Warehouse A7 - 15 units
dvdrw - Warehouse A7 - 91 units

As you can see, I should be getting 12 units as the Result, however I'm getting the value of 15 units (HDD drive)

Comment: So it kind of sounds like you should use the same pattern, but instead make columns for various `AA.Familia` values. Your exact needs still aren't entirely clear to me (nor is the relationship between the tables' source data). Without create table statements with inserts, I suspect we'll just be circling around each other for a while. If you want to update the question with this information, I can try an edit.

Comment: I'll try to explain it, otherwise I'll update the question again. So, coalesce is amazing because it always select the warehouses with the order I need. However, what I really need is something that, in pair with the coalesce, gives me the MIN of those Results.
So, I want to give priority to the warehouse A7 always but since the A8 warehouse only has one type of component, if there's less units than in the A7 warehouse, I need to consider that.

Comment: I've placed a picture (4th edit) to help you understand the problem.